# In Hyperledger Fabric, will an orderer that belongs to an org that is not part of a channel violates data confidentiality?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Based on the documentation of Hyperledger Fabric, it is possible to have a channel (e.g., channel A) that has two member organizations (e.g., Org1 and Org2) that uses an orderer that belongs to a different organization (e.g., Org3).

Since the orderer receives transactions after the **execute** phase to perform ordering, does this mean that the orderer belonging to Org3 has a copy of the transactions of channel A?

Does this defeat the use of channels in terms of data confidentiality?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the orderer keeps a copy of all channel it orderers.

In the case you need privacy from orderer you can use Private Data, it isn't propagated to Orderer, is distributed in a peer to peer model using gossip protocol.

Here is the full documentation: 
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private-data/private-data.html

Any further question comment here and I edit this when possible.

Comment: If org3 has no peer in the channel, would it be better if we simply avoid using an orderer of org3?  Or are there cases that it is advantageous to use orderer from org3 but just use private data for the transactions of org1 and org2?

Comment: Yes,  I would avoid delegating the orderer role to other organization unless it is a requirement.
Now we have raft consensus that is production suitable. With RAFT you can distribute orderer nodes across organizations in a crash fault tolerance architecture, that way org1 and org2 can be ordereres.